# Why TrayIcon doesn't appear?

Tags: java, image, swing, system-tray, trayicon

I'm trying to add a TrayIcon inside a Tray that already appears. I'm new in Java so i can be calling wrong methods. Could someone help me please? The code i use is:

```
if (!SystemTray.isSupported()) {
    System.out.println("SystemTray is not supported");
    return;
}

final SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("systemtray.png");
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "The Tip Text", popup);
trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
try {
    tray.add(trayIcon);
} catch (AWTException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

ps.: image is in the same package of code.

Comment: Is `Toolkit` placed in the same package as this code? If not, Java might search in the wrong place.

Comment: Unhapply there are no exceptions @Sanjeev

Comment: I don't know where is Toolkit. I just called it as is shown in Oracle Examples. Have I to do something else? @maddening

Comment: OK, `Toolkit` is Oracle's class. Then it surely searches for image relatively to its own directory - if you can pass it absolute path to file, or relative path to `Toolkit` class it would work. But it would also complicate your code as you'll need to figure out right path before you could use its `getImage(String)` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example. Look to see where you may be going wrong.

- Get Image 
  [image]

  ```
  Image image= ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/stackoverflow1.png"));
  ```

---

- File structure

[image]

---

- Complete running program

Here

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class HideToSystemTray extends JFrame {

    TrayIcon trayIcon;
    SystemTray tray;

    HideToSystemTray() throws IOException {
        super("SystemTray test");
        System.out.println("creating instance");
        try {
            System.out.println("setting look and feel");
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to set LookAndFeel");
        }
        if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
            System.out.println("system tray supported");
            tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

            Image image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/stackoverflow1.png"));
            ActionListener exitListener = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Exiting....");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            };
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
            MenuItem defaultItem = new MenuItem("Exit");
            defaultItem.addActionListener(exitListener);
            popup.add(defaultItem);
            defaultItem = new MenuItem("Open");
            defaultItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    setVisible(true);
                    setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
                }
            });
            popup.add(defaultItem);
            trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "SystemTray Demo", popup);
            trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
        } else {
            System.out.println("system tray not supported");
        }
        addWindowStateListener(new WindowStateListener() {
            public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e) {
                if (e.getNewState() == ICONIFIED) {
                    try {
                        tray.add(trayIcon);
                        setVisible(false);
                        System.out.println("added to SystemTray");
                    } catch (AWTException ex) {
                        System.out.println("unable to add to tray");
                    }
                }
                if (e.getNewState() == 7) {
                    try {
                        tray.add(trayIcon);
                        setVisible(false);
                        System.out.println("added to SystemTray");
                    } catch (AWTException ex) {
                        System.out.println("unable to add to system tray");
                    }
                }
                if (e.getNewState() == MAXIMIZED_BOTH) {
                    tray.remove(trayIcon);
                    setVisible(true);
                    System.out.println("Tray icon removed");
                }
                if (e.getNewState() == NORMAL) {
                    tray.remove(trayIcon);
                    setVisible(true);
                    System.out.println("Tray icon removed");
                }
            }
        });
        setIconImage(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/stackoverflow1.png")));

        setVisible(true);
        setSize(300, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new HideToSystemTray();
    }
}
```

---

- Result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code is absolutely fine, probably your Image can't be found.
If you're using eclipse it should be located in your project folder.

Answer (score 1):

If image cannot be found (as @Leo Pflug noticed your code seems fine), try this little trick I've been using:

```
// place this class in the same directory as your image
public class Resources {
    private Resources() {}
}

// then to obtain Image
Image image = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(
    Resources.class.getResourceAsStream("systemtray.png"));
```

It will guarantee that Java would search for a `systemtray.png` in EXACTLY the same directory as `Resources.java` (`Resoures.class`) file.

I suspect that `Toolkit` searches for it in its own directoery while you placed image in the same directory as your code, and thus the problem.