# How to set system-tray icon using only AWT

Tags: java, awt, trayicon

I've created a calculator using AWT Frames. I wanna know how to add a tray-icon to my Cal. I can only use AWT not Swing.

Comment: *"I can only use AWT not Swing."*  Why?

Comment: Because I am doing this as a project. they want it in AWT. :)

Comment: Which then leads to the question, why do ***they*** want it using AWT?

Answer (score 2):

```
final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("pathToImage"));
final SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

try {
    tray.add(trayIcon);
} catch (AWTException e) {
    System.out.println("TrayIcon could not be added.");
}
```

Found at this page http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html

You should also check if `SystemTray` is supported before using the following snippet

```
if (!SystemTray.isSupported()) {
    System.out.println("SystemTray is not supported");
    //..
}
```

Note that `SystemTray` is from package `java.awt` as per your request.

Comment: cannot find symbol  |  symbol : method createImage(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)   |   location : class Cal   |   final TrayIcon trayicon = new TrayIcon(createImage("cal.png","tray icon"));    | error's in the last line. at the start point of (createImage("cal.png"..........))

Comment: @user271865 I edited to load the image using `java.awt.Toolkit`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for figuring out I forgot the parenthesis.

Comment: You're welcome.  When I see a good answer that requires a minor tweak, I'll make the change. :)  If the answer was rubbish, I'd just down vote and move on.  ;)

Comment: nope. no compiling or runtime errors. but icon doesn't show up. I tried with different resolution of icons. but still no.

Comment: @user271865 check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753252/why-trayicon-doesnt-appear maybe you will have more success with `ImageIO` instead of `Toolkit`